# Jsf form Print preview

Tags: java, javascript, css, jsf, jsf-1.2

I have a JSF form of view *.jspx page. The form has around 20 fields. I have a print preview button, that would open a new browser window and show print preview of this form, making all the form content as read only.

I have done a bit of workaround like setting a boolean flag in Managed bean as showprintPreview. This approach has almost done the job by showing all the fields in readonly and buttons as disabled mode. 
But, I don't want to change the backing bean object.

I'd like to show the print preview with css or javascript for a jsf form.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried another way by using onclick on print preview button that would call predefined, window.print() js function. But its displaying all the buttons as well. I would like to hide buttons like submit, back etc in print preview and show all the input fields like text, textarea etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would reuse part of page wich you want to print. Create new page only with this reusable part. then on button action open this new page in new window (target="_blank") in print preview you mentioned.